# Azure module cannot be loaded in Mac OS

Tags: macos, azure, powershell

When I try to connect to azure:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
```

Getting following error:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount : The 'Connect-AzureRmAccount' command was found in the module 'AzureRM.Profile.Netcore', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module AzureRM.Profile.Netcore'.
```

But when trying to Import-Module AzureRM.Profile.Netcore, it gives me this error:

```
Import-Module : Could not find a part of the path '/Users/Gurnor/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureRM.Resources/6.4.0/Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.format.ps1xml'.
```

Googled above error but cant find any answers? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you check [this the latest version](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Netcore/0.9.1) `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Netcore -RequiredVersion 0.9.1 `?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT Am at 0.13.1

Comment: Try to refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurermps-maclinux?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to install and import the module.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by uninstalling the AzureRM module(s) and switching to the new Az modules.

1. In `pwsh`, run: `Uninstall-AzureRm`
2. Then: `Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser`
3. If you run `Enable-AzureRmAlias`, most scripts using "AzureRm" cmdlets should work.

If you still have issues, try running `Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRM -AllVersions` and see if you need to uninstall more modules, I think my problem was that between brew and terminal and vscode, I had several versions installed. I was only able to get things working smoothly by eliminating everything except the Az module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/uninstall-azurerm?view=azps-2.7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.7.0